# How to obtain input columns for Spark MLlib Linear Regression (SGD) Model

Tags: apache-spark, machine-learning, linear-regression, apache-spark-mllib

I've successfully built the LinearRegressionModel in Spark(MLlib).

My requirement is to obtain the input columns used for building the model. Is there any possible way to achieve this ?

For eg. Consider, I've used "ColA", "ColB" and "ColC" for building the model. Once after I constructed the model, is there any way to obtain these column names from the model object ?

Comment: You have chosen the columns to use with LR. I'm not sure I get your question...

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR** No, it's not possible.

You should use your `Pipeline` and `Transformers` to know what was used and at what step.